# Error: "Warning (unlock-file): Unlocking file: Invalid argument, .emacs.d/.org-id-locations, ignored"

Tags: org-mode, org-id, unlock-file

I'm using Emacs with org-mode and the org-id option under Microsoft Windows 10.

GNU Emacs 29.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2024-01-18

Org mode version 9.6.15 (release_9.6.15 @ c:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-29.2/share/emacs/29.2/lisp/org/)

When I use the "Saving all org buffers" command by hitting "s" in an agenda view, the following error message is shown in the 'Warnings' buffer:

> Warning (unlock-file): Unlocking file: Invalid argument,
> c:/Users/myusername/Documents/directoryname/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations, ignored

So it seems to be related to the file '.org-id-locations' and this is very annoying, as the Warnings buffer pops up each time when I save my changes..

This **only happens** after I have created a new org-mode heading and created a link to it, so that a new property value ':ID:' has been created..

However this even happens if the new heading is not displayed in the agenda, from where I'm saving, nor does the warning appear, when I just save the .org file with the new headings and properties...

How can I narrow down this annoying problem?

How can I narrow down the problem?

Comment: What happens if you say `M-: (unlock-file "c:/Users/myusername/Documents/directoryname/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations") RET`? Is there a buffer visiting that file perhaps? If there is, try killing the buffer (get a backup before and after saving that buffer too, just in case) and see if the warning goes away.

Comment: There is a dot in the name `.org-id-locations`, so please check again carefully. Also, add the backtrace to your question between triple backticks (the key to the left of the `1` key) so that it will be somewhat readable. Did you use the double quotes in the expression, exactly as I showed you in my comment above? Just cut and paste the expression as is, but if you type it in, make sure it's **exactly** as shown.

Comment: @NickD thank you again and sorry, if I'm doing something wrong..

I copied the following line into an empty buffer and did Ctrl-C Ctrl-E for evaluating the buffer, is that what you meant?
'(unlock-file "c:/Users/myuser/Documents/mydirectory/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations")'

the only result was a warning, this time:
'Warning (unlock-file): Unlocking file: Invalid argument, c:/Users/myuser/Documents/mydirectory/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations, ignored'

Comment: @NickD this time, there was no Backtrace, last time it was :

´´´Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable c:/Users/myuserDocuments/mydirectory/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations) (unlock-file c:/Users/myuser/Documents/mydirectory/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations) (progn (unlock-file c:/Users/myuserDocuments/mydirectory/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations)) elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil) eval-last-sexp(nil) funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil) command-execute(eval-last-sexp) There is no open buffer with the file org-id-locations´´´